# I can't login, although I'm registered on askubuntu.com

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, launchpad, google+

I've got a Launchpad and a goggle+ - account, but I can't login to askubuntu, although I'm registered (my username is lowereastside) cause always comes the question for „openID“. Am I too stupid to check this? How can I login to askubuntu.com, cause I can't find more informations about this openID neither on Launchpad nore on google+. Therefore i beg you to give me a little help, so that I'm able to login "askubuntu.com“!
With many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't login how did you post this question?

Comment: Did you login from another computer before?

Comment: @stonedsquirrel The account used to post this question is [unregistered](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/139147/paulus-rutter). It was posted on main and migrated here.